# A set $U$ is open iff it is union of open balls

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Consider the collection $\mathcal{T} = \{ U \subset X: \forall u \in U, \exists r>0 \; \; , B_r(u) \subset U \}$. We showed that $(X, \mathcal{T} )$ is a topological space. $\mathbf{Homework }:$ Please show that $U \in \mathcal{T} \iff U = \bigcup_{u \in U} B_r(u) $

#### Attempt:

Suppose $U$ is open. We want to show that $U = \bigcup_{u \in U} B_r(u)$. Since $U$ is open, for all $u \in U$, we can find some $r>0$ such that $u \in B_r(u) \subset \bigcup_{u \in U} B_r(u)$. So that $U \subset \bigcup_{u \in U} B_r(u)$. Now, if $x \in \bigcup_{u \in U} B_r(u)$, then we can find some $u' \in U$ such that $x \in B_r(u) $. And so $x \in U$. Therefore, we have shown that $U = \bigcup_{u \in U} B_r(u)$.

Conversely, Suppose $U = \bigcup_{u \in U} B_r(u)$. We want to show that $U$ is open. Pick some $u \in U$. So there is some $u' \in U$ such that $u \in B_r(u') \subset U$. So $U$ is open.

Is this a correct solution? thanks

Comment: I would write $B_{r_u}(u)$, to signify that the radius might not be the same for every point. As far as I can tell, though, the proof is correct.